# circled digit zero and circled digit one in Linux Libertine Type 1?

Tags: pdftex, libertine, type1

In https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2460/fontsupport.htm and https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/24ea/fontsupport.htm we see that Linux Libertine contains ① and ⓪, respectively.  Is it possible to get these symbols for the `latex` and `pdflatex` engines?  When I search for any commands that could produce, say,  ⓪, on my local installation, I get nothing:

```
$ locate libertine| grep sty | xargs egrep -ari "circle.*zero"
$
```

Or are these symbols simply not included in the type 1 versions of Linux Libertine?

(This question explicitly does NOT concern UTF-8 engines.)

Comment: the glyphs are in the pfb, but they are not encoded, so you would have to create suitable tfm + enc file yourself.

Comment: To create suitable tfm and enc files, read the documentation for otftotfm.

Answer (score 0):

Those glyphs are not available in the type 1 versions.  They *are* available in the otf versions at uni24EA and uni2460.

Comment: that is wrong, I can access them, this picture has been made with LinLibertineT.pfb: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry4jB.png

Comment: How did you access them using latex or pdflatex?

Comment: with a local enc file which maps the glyphs to encoded positions (but the metrics are naturally wrong as I didn't generated the tfm for the test.)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to install the libertine-legacy package available at CTAN. The type 1 fonts and associated files support all the glyphs of the otf fonts. Be sure to remove the current libertine package.

Comment: libertine-legacy is marked as obsolete at CTAN… Do you know, by chance, whether installing libertinus-type1 would do? `locate libertinus| grep sty | xargs egrep -ari "circle.*zero"` returns nothing on my machine.

Comment: "obsolete" but perfectly usable.  I doubt that libertinus-type1 would support non-standard encodings.